# select lines with duplicate columns by a specific value

Tags: regex, perl, sed, awk, pattern-matching

I have an input like this:

```
LineA parameter1 parameter2 56  
LineB parameter1 parameter2 87
LineB parameter1 parameter2 56
LineB parameter1 parameter2 90
LineC parameter1 parameter2 40
```

I want to print each line but, if the first column (`$1`) is duplicated, only print the line with the highest value in the last column (`$4`).

So the output should look like this:

```
LineA parameter1 parameter2 56
LineB parameter1 parameter2 90
LineC ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below(assuming field 4 is >= 0 throughout)

Array `b` is used to track the highest value in field 4 for unique values in field 1. Array `a` (keyed by field 1) contains the corresponding record. As each record is processed, the record is added to array `a` and field 4 is added to array `b` if 
 1. a value is encountered in field 1 for the first time or 2. the value in field 4 exceeds the existing value in `b` for the value in field 1. 
Finally, array `a` is printed out.

```
 awk '$4 > b[$1] {a[$1] = $0; b[$1] = $4}
 END{for (x in a) {print a[x]}}'
```

Comment: +1, but you only need to check `$4 > b[$1]}` -- if `$1` has not yet been seen, then `b[$1]` will be treated as zero. More descriptive variable names may help.

Comment: @user2245731, note that the order of output is not guaranteed to be the same as the input: awk associative arrays do not preserve insertion order.

Comment: Thanks, but could you add a little explanation of the code. Thanks :)

Comment: @user2245731, added some explanation. Hope it clarifies, description is not my strong point

Comment: @1_CR thanks. I'm a rookie, so ,sometime I need an extra help.

Comment: I actually meant that the *entire* condition only needs to be `$4>b[$1]` -- you don't need `!($1 in a)` at all. If $1 is not in `a` then b[$1] == 0 therefore $4 will be greater then b[1]. Assuming values in column 4 are all positive.

Comment: @glennjackman, thank you, edited the answer again. But please note that this fails when field 4 has negative values throughout for a particular key value from field 1. Hopefully in the OP's situation this case does not occur

Answer (score 2):

Code for GNU [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk 'BEGIN {SUBSEP=OFS} $4>a[$1,$2,$3] {a[$1,$2,$3]=$4} END {for (i in a) {print i,a[i]}}' file
```

Comment: unreadable. try `awk 'BEGIN {SUBSEP=OFS} $4>a[$1,$2,$3] {a[$1,$2,$3]=$4} END {same as what you have}'`

Answer (score 0):

Another way in `awk`:

```
awk '
fld1!=$1 && NR>1 {print line}
fld1==$1 {line=(fld4>$4)?line:$0;next}
{line=$0;fld1=$1;fld4=$4;next}
END{print line}' file
```